# ¿Como convertir elementos de un array de string a float?

Tags: javascript, array, string, float

Tengo este `array` (valores `string`)

```
locations = [
    {lat: "-31.563910", lng: "147.154312"},
    {lat: "-33.718234", lng: "150.363181"},
    {lat: "-33.727111", lng: "150.371124"}
  ]
```

y quiero que el `array` quede así (valores `float`)

```
locations2 = [
    {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
    {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
    {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124}
  ]
```

Intente esto:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
       locations2=locations.push(
         {lat:parseFloat(locations[i].lat),lng:parseFloat(locations[i].lng)}
       );
      }
```

Pero no funciona manda el error:

> locations2.push is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
    var locations = [
        {lat: "-31.563910", lng: "147.154312"},
        {lat: "-33.718234", lng: "150.363181"},
        {lat: "-33.727111", lng: "150.371124"}
    ];
    var locations2 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
           locations2.push(
             {lat:parseFloat(locations[i].lat),lng:parseFloat(locations[i].lng)}
           );
    }
```

Comment: Entonces el símbolo "=" es lo que esta mal?

Comment: `var locations2 = []` es para asegurarte que tienes un arreglo de objectos. Puedes interpretar `locations2.push({...})` como: inserta en el arreglo `locations2` este nuevo objecto entre corchetes.